Get access token using just the client Id and Principal name while calling a springboot project from a Spring project
My project is built using Spring (not Springboot) framework. I am making use of Spring security to get access token from another service which is built using SpringBoot.
Now, since I do not see oauth package in Spring Security of Spring framework project, I am not sure how to get access token here.
I don’t have username/password/private token of jwt. What I have is client Registration id and principal name. Can anyone share some example and reference, how to achieve this?
I tried searching for the solution on internet but everywhere it is about SpringBoot + Spring Security.
The jwt token authentication way doesn’t seem possible as I do not have the privateJwtToken.

Client secret is needed to generate access token, access token is like a secret/password using which server knows who is the principal sending the request, in any cloud provider whenever you setup and app you always get a client secret along with client id, so that user can obtain access token
